# generating combinations of combinations

Tags: combinations

I'm trying to generate code which will take the components (i.e, a-f) of various combination permutations (combo) one, two, three, or four units long using these six components and provide various non duplicating combinations of combinations (combo.combo) which contain all of the components (i.e., [ab + cdef and ac + bde + f] but not [ae + bc + df and aef + bc + d]).

It would be nice if this code could allow me to 1) input the number of components, 2) input the min and max unit length per combo, 3) input the min and max number of combos per combo.combo, and 4) randomize the output list of combo.combos.

Maybe start with some kind of iteration loop to generate each version of the 720 possible component combinations (a-f) and then start pruning that list based on the set limiting parameters?  I've got some working knowledge of python and will get started, but any tips or suggestions are most welcome.

```
combo.combo    a    b    c    d    e    f
a.bcdef        1    1    1    1    1    1
ab.cdef        1    1    1    1    1    1
abc.def        1    1    1    1    1    1
abcd.ef        1    1    1    1    1    1
abcde.f        1    1    1    1    1    1
a.b.cdef       1    1    1    1    1    1
a.bc.def       1    1    1    1    1    1
a.bcd.ef       1    1    1    1    1    1
a.bcde.f       1    1    1    1    1    1
ab.c.def       1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I've found a lot of code which will generate combination permutations but not combinations of combinations.  I've included a binary matrix for the combination components, but am stuck on where to proceed from here or if this matrix is a false start (although a helpful visual aide.)

```
combo   a   b   c   d   e   f
a       1   0   0   0   0   0
b       0   1   0   0   0   0
c       0   0   1   0   0   0
d       0   0   0   1   0   0
e       0   0   0   0   1   0
f       0   0   0   0   0   1
ab      1   1   0   0   0   0
ac      1   0   1   0   0   0
ad      1   0   0   1   0   0
ae      1   0   0   0   1   0
af      1   0   0   0   0   1
bc      0   1   1   0   0   0
bd      0   1   0   1   0   0
be      0   1   0   0   1   0
bf      0   1   0   0   0   1
cd      0   0   1   1   0   0
ce      0   0   1   0   1   0
cf      0   0   1   0   0   1
de      0   0   0   1   1   0
df      0   0   0   1   0   1
ef      0   0   0   0   1   1
abc     1   1   1   0   0   0
abd     1   1   0   1   0   0
abe     1   1   0   0   1   0
abf     1   1   0   0   0   1
acd     1   0   1   1   0   0
ace     1   0   1   0   1   0
acf     1   0   1   0   0   1
ade     1   0   0   1   1   0
adf     1   0   0   1   0   1
aef     1   0   0   0   1   1
bcd     0   1   1   1   0   0
bce     0   1   1   0   1   0
bcf     0   1   1   0   0   1
bde     0   1   0   1   1   0
bdf     0   1   0   1   0   1
bef     0   1   0   0   1   1
cde     0   0   1   1   1   0
cdf     0   0   1   1   0   1
cef     0   0   1   0   1   1
def     0   0   0   1   1   1
abcd    1   1   1   1   0   0
abce    1   1   1   0   1   0
abcf    1   1   1   0   0   1
abde    1   1   0   1   1   0
abdf    1   1   0   1   0   1
abef    1   1   0   0   1   1
acde    1   0   1   1   1   0
acdf    1   0   1   1   0   1
acef    1   0   1   0   1   1
adef    1   0   0   1   1   1
bcde    0   1   1   1   1   0
bcdf    0   1   1   1   0   1
bcef    0   1   1   0   1   1
bdef    0   1   0   1   1   1
cdef    0   0   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: which one of two you expect to output ? ae.bc.df or aef.bc.d ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking?  I would want all the possible combinations of combinations that met my parameters to output.

Comment: then I suggest you give one full example of : 1.input, 2. parameters. 3. expected output. Currently its not clear at all what you meant by quote : `but not [ae + bc + df and aef + bc + d]` ?

Comment: I was trying to illustrate what I meant by "non duplicating" -- in that example the combination "bc" is duplicated within both combination combinations, so that would not work for what I want the code to do.

Comment: so, lets say you have input :  1) components {a,b,c} 2) min combo.length = 1, max combo.length=2 3) min combo.combo.length = 1 max combo.combo.length = 3, then what do you expect as output for that example ?

Answer (score 0):

The approach which first comes to mind is this:

1. generate all the combinations using the given components (which you already did :) )
2. treat the resulting combinations as a new set of components (so instead of a, b,...,f your set will contain a, ab, abc, ...)
3. generate all the combinations from the second set
4. from the new set of combinations only keep those which apply to your condition (it's not very clear from your example what the constraint is)

This, of course, has sky-high exponential complexity, since you'll have to backtrack twice and step 3 has way more possibilities.

It's very possible that there's a more efficient algorithm, starting from the constraint ("non duplicating combinations of combinations which contain all of the components").

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I've edited to be more specific as to what tasks I want the code to perform after introducing the problem.